# 2d vector for-loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, types

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
int main() {

  vector<vector<int>> map{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                          {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
  for (int j : map) {
    for (int i :j) {
      cout << i ;
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Above code, there is an error in **int j : map**
But when i change 'int' to 'auto', the code is working well

My question is what is proper type for 2d vector such as map?
Why **int** is not working for 2d vector?

Comment: What do you think `map`'s contained type is?  Is it int?  If not, is it convertible to int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use like this. Because first for loop search in `vector<vector<int>>`. So j type must be `vector<int>` for first layer. My English is too bad so sorry i try the explain this. I hope this is helpfully.

```
for (vector<int> &j : map) {
    for (int i : j) {
      cout << i ;
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
```

Comment: While this will compile, it is not efficient because you're copying each inner vector.  Make `j` a reference.